# IIS 8 not running embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, iis-8

Can you please help.

I have JavaScript code on my master page and its **working fine in visual studio** and its also **running fine on another production server**. However its not working on the new server (in IIS8).

Code sample

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $(document).gmediaShadows(); 
            $('.lightbox').lightbox();

            $('.success').hide();
            $('.unsuccess').hide();

            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                        dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showOn: "button",
                        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
                        buttonImageOnly: true,
                        onSelect: function() {}
                });

            $(".radio-set").buttonset();
            $(".jquery-button").button();            

        });
  </script>
```

I have already set permissions on the Application folder for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS users. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, not on the web server.  How exactly is this code "not running"?  Is there an error in the browser console?  Is the code in the page source at all?  How specifically does it fail in the browser?

Comment: Javascript isn't executed on the server but on the client, whatever your problem is, it is certainly not in the code. There might be a lot of reasons for failure though, a quick glance at the console or network panel of your developer tools would certainly be a good start.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response guys. the error on console says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @Linda: That means jQuery hasn't been loaded.  Where in the page's code do you load jQuery?  This has literally *nothing* to do with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading jquery. Try adding this script to the beginning.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```